# Is there a way to generate custom BuildConfig.java file when deploying from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, adt, android-gradle-plugin

We have recently converted our app to run under Android Studio and gradle.  Our build.gradle file has custom fields generated for different build variants of BuildConfig.java.  We still need to run our application in eclipse to run our robolectric tests.  Is it possible to have eclipse generate a BaseConfig.java with custom variables other than DEBUG?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution to your question, but you might want to consider running robolectric from Gradle.
There are many tutorials if you search for it and you probably already set this up.

If you're concerned about debugging robolectric tests you can do so with Android Studio as well. [A little bit of classpath hacking](http://kostyay.name/android-studio-robolectric-gradle-getting-work/) may be needed in Android Studio or just use [IDEA 14](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP).